# Using cellRendererFramework in Angular 5 ag-grid data table

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-directives, ag-grid

I am building a app in angular 5. In my HTML page, I have a table which shows the data on being queried. This data is being displayed in **ag-grid** using  directive. One of the column in grid is displayed as HTML link. I am using **cellRendererFramework** feature to show the values in column as link.
It is working fine and displays the link on the value for that column in table for each row. My requirement is that I want to pass additional parameter to **cellRendererFramework** component from the main component class. The reason I need this is because when the link is clicked the Angular app displays new components using angular routers and I need to pass multiple values to other component.

I am not sure how to pass parameters to **cellRendererFramework** class.

**Column definitions of data grid**

```
this.columnDefs = [
      { headerName: "Hotel ID", field: "HotelID", width: 500,
        cellRendererFramework: LinkcompComponent },
      { headerName: "Account Number", field: "AccountNumber" , width: 700 },
      { headerName: "Customer Name", field: "PartyName", width: 670  }
    ];
```

**HTML** file of **cellRendererFramework** component

```
<a [routerLink]="['/trxDetails',params.value]">{{ params.value }}</a>
```

Is it possible to pass additional parameters to **cellRendererFramework** component?

Answer (score 11):

Did you find a way to do this ? I am in exactly the same situation as you. Need to pass the "routerLink" as a parameter to this cellRendererFramework component, so that I can make it generic and use the component in multiple ag-grids / pages.

```
@Component({
// template: '<a routerLink="/trade-detail">{{params.value}}</a>'
template: '<a [routerLink]="inRouterLink">{{params.value}}</a>'
})
export class RouterLinkRendererComponent implements AgRendererComponent {
   @Input('inRouterLink') public inRouterLink = "/trade-detail";
   params: any;
```

---

EDIT

Ok, found the answer on their website itself after a little more looking.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#complementing-cell-renderer-params

So, in my case, I pass the params like so:

*BlotterHomeComponent class*

```
columnDefs = [
{
  headerName: 'Status', field: 'status',
  cellRendererFramework: RouterLinkRendererComponent,
  cellRendererParams: {
    inRouterLink: '/trade-detail'
  }
},
```

*RouterLinkRenderer Class*

```
@Component({
template: '<a [routerLink]="params.inRouterLink">{{params.value}}</a>'
})
export class RouterLinkRendererComponent implements AgRendererComponent {
  params: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  refresh(params: any): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```