# A-g Grid router link on row selection

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I can't seem to get the router link to work with Ag grid.

If I put the router `link ="url"` then whenever I press anything on the grid it transfers me to the other page but I want it so only pressing the individual row will send me to another page with the Id.

Is it possible to use the `rowSelected` event to go to another page or use `RouterLink` in the ts file?

Comment: I simple [googled it](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=ag+grid+router&rlz=1C1OKWM_pt-BRBR783BR783&oq=ag+grid+router&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2447j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and found [this page](https://www.ag-grid.com/example-angular-dynamic/). You just need to manage a JSON to route it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using cellRendererFramework in Angular 5 ag-grid data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127914/using-cellrendererframework-in-angular-5-ag-grid-data-table)

Answer (score 3):

it sounds like you want the [onRowClicked event](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#selection).

```
gridOptions.onRowClicked = params => {
   console.log(params);
   if ( params.node && params.node.selected ) {
       var id = params.node.data.id; // or whatever the field is called
       link = `url/${id}`; // however you are doing navigation
   }
}
```